# Need clarification on java garbage collection Copying Collectors

Tags: java, garbage-collection

This is just to clarify my understanding of java garbage collection copying collectors.

Is it the same logic as =>

**I am moving the bunch of grapes from one box to other and all grapes which are not in bunch are left there in box which are eligible for garbage collection.**

Some may find my understanding stupid, as the point I want to clear here, is that the time consumed in checking the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grapes example is fine.

When the GC works most efficiently, it assume only a small portion of the data will need to be copied to the next space.  If you are keeping most of the data, the space (eden or survivor) might not be large enough or you have too much medium lived data. (Which the GC doesn't handle particularly well)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Java uses **'Mark And Sweep Algorithm'** for making objects eligible for garbage collection.

This is similar to your grapes example. 
JVM marks all the objects which are no longer referenced with value '1' ,after which all non-eligible objects remains with value '0'. When ever the algorithm runs it sweeps all objects whose value is of '1'.

Comment: It uses Mark and Sweep when you enable it with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` but only for the tenured space.